# How to change background image of a collapsible through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, background-image

I have a background image of a down arrow to show the drawer being closed, and I would like it to be changed to an up arrow when you open the drawer.

I have tried adding to my JS function to open and close the drawer but my inexperience is showing.

I have included the function that I used to open and close the collapisble, I just need to either add upon that function, or create a new one to switch the two arrow images when you open and close the drawer.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible").forEach((coll) => {
          coll.addEventListener("click", () => {
            coll.classList.toggle("active");

            const content = coll.nextElementSibling;

            if (content.style.maxHeight) {
              content.style.maxHeight = null;
              // Add this:
              content.style.borderWidth = 0;
            } else {
              content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
              // And this:
              content.style.borderWidth = "1px";
            }
          });
        });
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition:
    border 0.2s ease-out,
    max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0px solid #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {

  background-image: url("../images/upArrow.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 5%;

#backArrow {

  width: 1%;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 2px;

}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible"> Consult Logs </button>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="column">
            <p>Ensure the disc strength is not at “0”.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img src="../images/discStrength.png" alt="Picture of Logs">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is the same question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455037/up-and-down-arrow-onclick

Comment: It seems to be a different scenario. I am not using a js sleeve. I appreciate you trying to point me in the right direction though.

Comment: thats why i did not flag this question but it can help you the way in js so commented. Ok trying to solve this and will let you know.

Comment: i hope this is what you are looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/3t4mv8cr/2/

Comment: Hello I just got back into the office and tried to implement your code. It doesn't seem to work, even when I copy your code into a new document.

Comment: As clarification, I want to either replace the background image (a down arrow), with another url/background image (up arrow), or rotate the background image 180 degrees on click. You example code works only within jsfiddle and I don't think is transforming the background. I am unsure of why the code doesn't work at all though.

Comment: In My jsfiddle i have added some css and js which you have to include but as you are saying, you want to rotate the background image then i think i will try to create new jsfiddle with another solution.

Comment: is it ok if i use arrow icon rather then background image or you only want background image to rotate?

Comment: It is totally okay, thank you for helping me. The question has been answered on my other threads but I would still love to see your code as a learning experience.

Comment: i think this is the best version you will like. Let me know if you like it so i can post this as answer so it might help other people too. https://jsfiddle.net/2pemdtaL/1/

Answer (score 1):

create two classes in your CSS, one for the up arrow and another for the down arrow, then add and remove them with javascript.

Note:

1- add the down arrow `onload` out of the function.

2- use small-size svg/png. I just used these links as an example, and the first load takes longer.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
// add up arrow on load
btn.classList.add("btndown");

document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible").forEach((coll) => {
    coll.addEventListener("click", () => {
      coll.classList.toggle("active");

      const content = coll.nextElementSibling;
      const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      btn.classList.add("btndown");

      if (content.style.maxHeight) {
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
        // Add this:
        content.style.borderWidth = 0;

      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        // And this:
        content.style.borderWidth = "1px";
        btn.classList.remove("btndown");
        btn.classList.add("btnup");
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition:
    border 0.2s ease-out,
    max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0px solid #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* 
button {

  background-image: url("../images/upArrow.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 5%;
} */

.btnup {
    background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1634/1634156.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 5%;
  }
  .btndown {
    background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1634/1634155.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 5%;
  }

#backArrow {

  width: 1%;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 2px;

}
```

```html
  <button type="button" class="collapsible" id="btn"> Consult Logs </button>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="column">
            <p>Ensure the disc strength is not at “0”.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img src="../images/discStrength.png" alt="Picture of Logs">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Thanks for Oskar Grosser, `style.backgroundImage` won't remove previously added inline styles.

```
coll.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/downArrow.svg)'
```

---

Use `style.cssText` to change background img

```js
coll.style.cssText = 'background-image:url(../images/downArrow.svg)'
```

Comment: Instead of `style.cssText`, prefer to assign to the [camel-cased CSS property on `style`](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-camel-cased-attribute) directly, here i.e. `style.backgroundImage`. That way you don't remove previously added inline styles.